# Intellij Idea Missing Diagram Context Menu

Tags: intellij-idea, uml, diagramming

I am trying to generate UML class diagrams in Intellij Idea 15. Everywhere on the net, including Jetbrains' site indicates that I need to open the context menu on a package -> Diagram

The problem is that I don't have the diagram context menu. I checked my plugin menu and there is no UML plugin active or listed, which seems to indicate there is no built in UML diagram support. I also tried Ctrl+U and also Ctrl+Alt+Shift+U shortcuts with packages selected

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: If you have Community Edition read also the comments beneath the answer in the linked question.

Comment: You are correct. Community edition does not include UML. I only wish that Jetbrains website was a little more clear.